# Keep getting an Error when setting up onPrepare in Protractor configuration file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor, automated-tests

I am creating my first protractor framework and I am setting up my on prepare in my configuration file.

I keep getting an error `X` symbol and I can't figure out why.

```js
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',


  specs: ['PageObjectLocator1.js'],

  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome'
  }

  onPrepare = function {

    //place global functions here

  }


}
```

Here's a screen shot too.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You had issues with the syntax, where you needed `:` to separate the key (onPrepare) and a value (function).

Also you are missing a comma (`,`) between `capabilities` and `onPrepare` keys.
Here is code that you need:

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['PageObjectLocator1.js'],
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome'
  },
  onPrepare: function() {
    //your code 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

onPrepare should look like this

```
onPrepare: function() {
   //your code
}
```

and in your case

```
exports.config = {
   seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
   specs: ['PageObjectLocator1.js'],
   capabilities: { browserName: 'chrome' },  //don't forget the comma
   onPrepare: function() {
      //your code
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks man.  I tried that can still got an error.`exports.config = {
seleniumAddress : 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',


    specs: ['PageObjectLocator1.js'],
    
    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome'
      } 
    
onPrepare: function() {
    //your code
 }

 `   I don't understand why I am getting this red x next to on Prepare????

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot and add it to your post? I think you might be missing a comma after ...browserName: 'chrome' }  .onPrepare has to be separated as it is another property. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Sorry, forgot about the screenshot you've attached, my bad :) Surely it's a missing comma.